# Kivy/Buildozer No module named 'google.oauth2'

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I am developing an app with Kivy that uses a Google Sheets spreadsheet as its database. I am using gspread and google.auth.service_account to do this. When I run my app on the desktop, it works fine. When I compile it for android and try to run on the phone, it crashes (the app does make it to the phone).

These are the requirements in my buildozer.spec file:

```
    requirements = python3,kivy==1.11.1,openssl,KivyMD,google-auth-oauthlib,google-auth-httplib2,pyasn1,pyasn1-modules,rsa,requests,gspread
```

And the logcat:

```
05-01 18:28:03.346  2542  2568 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.helman.wtfmercado/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-05-01_1.txt
05-01 18:28:03.347  2542  2568 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
05-01 18:28:03.347  2542  2568 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.helman.wtfmercado/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
05-01 18:28:03.347  2542  2568 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.1 (default, Apr 29 2020, 16:44:54) 
05-01 18:28:03.347  2542  2568 I python  : [Clang 8.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang 40173bab62ec7462
05-01 18:28:03.347  2542  2568 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at ""
05-01 18:28:03.347  2542  2568 I python  : [INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] v0.104.1
05-01 18:28:03.349  2542  2568 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
05-01 18:28:04.022  2542  2568 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
05-01 18:28:04.066  2542  2568 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
05-01 18:28:04.083  2542  2568 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
05-01 18:28:04.084  2542  2568 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
05-01 18:28:04.085  2542  2568 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 V@331.0 (GIT@4c638fb, I557c585805) (Date:10/06/18)'>
05-01 18:28:04.085  2542  2568 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Qualcomm'>
05-01 18:28:04.085  2542  2568 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Adreno (TM) 540'>
05-01 18:28:04.085  2542  2568 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
05-01 18:28:04.085  2542  2568 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
05-01 18:28:04.085  2542  2568 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
05-01 18:28:04.106  2542  2568 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
05-01 18:28:04.107  2542  2568 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
05-01 18:28:04.115  2542  2568 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
05-01 18:28:04.173  2542  2568 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
05-01 18:28:04.378  2542  2568 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
05-01 18:28:04.378  2542  2568 I python  :    File "/home/sam/Desktop/WTF_Mercado/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 15, in <module>
05-01 18:28:04.378  2542  2568 I python  :    File "/home/sam/Desktop/WTF_Mercado/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/wtfmercado/gspread/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
05-01 18:28:04.379  2542  2568 I python  :    File "/home/sam/Desktop/WTF_Mercado/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/wtfmercado/gspread/auth.py", line 12, in <module>
05-01 18:28:04.379  2542  2568 I python  :  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.oauth2'
05-01 18:28:04.379  2542  2568 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Any advice on how to solve this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem.

> When I run my app on the desktop, it works fine. When I compile it for android and try to run on the phone, it crashes (the app does make it to the phone).

This line fixed the 
*[WARNING] stderr: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'* error:

file: **buildozer.spec**

```
requirements = python3,kivy,gspread,oauth2client,httplib2,pyopenssl,google-auth-oauthlib,pyasn1,pyasn1-modules,rsa,requests,google-auth-httplib2,openssl,google-api-python-client,google-auth,credentials,oauth2,google,cachetools,urllib3,chardet,idna,requests_oauthlib,oauthlib
```

make sure you have all the required libs installed on your machine via apt-get install or pip3 install.

also make sure to specify all the needed permission in **buildozer.spec** file, like:

```
android.permissions = INTERNET
```

[This helped me setup the Kivy and Buildozer machine](https://github.com/zaemiel/kivy-buildozer-installer)

Comment: What are all the required libs to have installed on your machine? I'm getting no module named google.cloud error